# What's the most elegant, Pythonic way to deduplicate two sequential records in a CSV and retaining one record?

Tags: python, list, csv, duplicates

I'm trying to deduplicate records in a CSV. I don't consider myself new to Python or to writing ETL scripts. I've done my due diligence and searched the S.O. pages and don't think this problem can be diluted to using SETs (like most deduplication problems).

**My goal is**: For all rows in which ORIG is equal to the previous row’s ORIG, among the two rows for which ORIG is equal, delete the row for which SEQ_TIME == 0.

As the Python dictum goes, "*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*" I've written code that I believe accomplishes this, but anyone would tell you it's extremely un-Pythonic. The CSV data looks like this, and my separate results CSV underneath that. Rows that meet the condition are highlighted in yellow for easy comparison.

[image: Data and Results]

Data as CSV text:

```
TRAIN#,SEQ#,ORIG,DEP,DEST,ARR,SEQ_TIME
A21,9,BPK,0.582986111,X66,0.584375,2
A21,10,X66,0.584375,CNLEMOYN,0.586805556,3.5
A21,11,CNLEMOYN,0.586805556,SMT,0.590972222,6
A21,12,SMT,0.590972222,,0.590972222,0
A21,13,SMT,0.590972222,CNCANAL,0.591666667,1
A21,14,CNCANAL,0.591666667,MEWILSPR,0.594791667,4.5
A21,15,MEWILSPR,0.594791667,,0.594791667,0
A21,16,MEWILSPR,0.594791667,MELEMONT,0.6,7.5
A21,17,MELEMONT,0.6,,0.6,6.5
A21,18,MELEMONT,0.6,MELOCKPO,0.605208333,0
A21,19,MELOCKPO,0.605208333,,0.605208333,0
A21,20,MELOCKPO,0.605208333,XUD,0.60625,2.5
A21,21,XUD,0.60625,JOL,0.607638889,2
```

And (un-Pythonic) code that I think accomplishes the goal is below.

```python
import csv

f = open("my_data.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, lineterminator="\n")
header = reader.next()

# Dict comprehension so we can refer to each column by index or name.
hdict = {value:index for index, value in enumerate(header)}

# Data is converted to a 2-D list, since I do other stuff with it later.
data = [row for row in reader]

# Main (un-pythonic) solution.
result = []
try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        row1 = data[i]
        row2 = data[i+1] # Will cause an IndexError on the last row.
        if row1[hdict["ORIG"]] == row2[hdict["ORIG"]]:
            if float(row1[hdict["SEQ_TIME"]]):
                result.append(row1)
            elif float(row2[hdict["SEQ_TIME"]]):
                result.append(row2)
            else:
                raise AssertionError("Two sequential rows with equivalent ORIG cannot both have SEQ_TIME == 0.")
            i += 1 # Force-skips to row3 in the next iteration, since row1 & row2 are handled above.
        else:
            result.append(row1)
        i += 1 # I'm brute-forcing a loop with a manual index.
except IndexError:    
    result.append(data[-1]) # Handle the last row.

# Write results to some other CSV.
g = open("my_results.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(g, lineterminator="\n")
writer.writerow(header)

for row in result:
    writer.writerow(result)

f.close()
g.close()
```

Although the `while True: break` idiom in Python is common and (I believe) sloppy coding, a `try: while True: go on forever: except IndexError` idiom is truly awful. Is there a more simple, elegant way to accomplish this task, such as a simple `for` loop?

One idea I pursued was using an iterable to control the cursor as it iterated through each row in a `for` loop:

```python
data_iterable = iter(data)

for row in data_iterable:
    row1 = row[:]
    row2 = data_iterable.next() # Controlling the cursor here.
    if row1[hdict["ORIG"]] == row2[hdict["ORIG"]]:
        if float(row1[hdict["SEQ_TIME"]]):
            result.append(row1)
        else:
            result.append(row2)
        # The AssertionError check can be omitted.
    else:
        result.append(row1) # If nothing unusual...
        result.append(row2) # append both rows.
```

The problem here is that this code only handles *even-numbered* duplicates and misses the *odd-numbered* duplicates.

Alternatively, we could iterate through the data twice, flagging rows we want to keep in a `keep_these_rows` list according to some ID like SEQ#. Then on the second pass, append only those rows to the result? But this seems equally clumsy to me and 2x as slow by necessity.

Any better solutions from the crowd?

**NOTES:**

- The `hdict` is an easy way to combine `csv.reader` and `csv.DictReader` capabilities, so you can refer to rows by name e.g. `row[hdict["ORIG"]]` or index e.g. `row[2]`.
- I read one post by @DSM mentioning the [itertools.GroupBy](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function as a contender. Would it do any good for us?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is posting images instead of text [not very useful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/487339)?

Comment: This is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DSM Added CSV as text, and mentioned your name for the itertools.groupby post. Thanks.

Comment: @ chepner I suppose you're right. I will not re-post this in the codereview.stackexchange.com board for fear of the "double poster" reprisal from various members, but if anyone can bump this post, please by all means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the groups you want to compress are all contiguous, then you're right that `itertools.groupby` could be useful.  Assuming that (say) we want to preserve SEQ_TIME == 0 cases if they're the only member of a group or if there are three contiguous entries with a SEQ_TIME == 0, we could do something like (Python 3 csv open style):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open("dedup.csv", newline="") as fp_in, open("dedup_out.csv", "w", newline="") as fp_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp_in)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp_out, reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(reader, key=lambda row: row["ORIG"]):
        group = list(group)
        if len(group) == 2:
            group = [row for row in group if not float(row["SEQ_TIME"]) == 0]
        writer.writerows(group)
```

which gives me

```
TRAIN#,SEQ#,ORIG,DEP,DEST,ARR,SEQ_TIME
A21,9,BPK,0.582986111,X66,0.584375,2
A21,10,X66,0.584375,CNLEMOYN,0.586805556,3.5
A21,11,CNLEMOYN,0.586805556,SMT,0.590972222,6
A21,13,SMT,0.590972222,CNCANAL,0.591666667,1
A21,14,CNCANAL,0.591666667,MEWILSPR,0.594791667,4.5
A21,16,MEWILSPR,0.594791667,MELEMONT,0.6,7.5
A21,17,MELEMONT,0.6,,0.6,6.5
A21,20,MELOCKPO,0.605208333,XUD,0.60625,2.5
A21,21,XUD,0.60625,JOL,0.607638889,2
```

where the group conditions can be adjusted as you need.  If you know there will never be any SEQ_TIME=0 cases you want to keep, the code could get even simpler, but this should give you a place to start.